# Testing internal methods for React 18 Components

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

Consider the following component:

```js
export default function Calc() {

    useEffect(() => {
       // do something
    })

    const Add = (x: number, y: number): number => {
        return x + y;
    }

    return (<></>)
}
```

I realize that in React <= 16, one would use enzyme: `shallow(<Calc />).instance().Add(2, 2)`. However, enzyme is no longer available in React 18 in favor of `@testing-library/react`.

So, the question is, **how do I unit test the 'Add' method** in React 18?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unit test the `Add` method in React 18, You can use the `@testing-library/react-hooks` package, which allows you to test custom hooks in isolation. The idea is to create a custom hook that wraps your component logic and exposes the `Add` method as a return value. For example, you can do something like this:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export const useCalc = () => {

  const Add = (x: number, y: number): number => {
    return x + y;
  };

  return { Add };
};

export default function Calc() {
  const { Add } = useCalc();

  return <></>;
}
```

And then:

```
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import { useCalc } from "./Calc";

test("Add method", () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useCalc());

  expect(result.current.Add(2, 2)).toBe(4);
  expect(result.current.Add(3, 5)).toBe(8);
});
```

If you use `render` instead of `renderHook`, you will still not be able to test the `Add` method directly, because `render` only returns the DOM elements rendered by your component, not the internal methods or state. You can only test the `Add` method indirectly by simulating user interactions that trigger the method and checking the expected output or behavior. For example, if your component has a button that calls the `Add` method and displays the result, you can use `fireEvent` or `userEvent` to click the button and use screen or `getByText` to check the result. However, this is not a unit test, but an integration test, because it involves testing multiple parts of your component together. If you want to unit test the `Add` method in isolation, you need to use `renderHook` with a custom hook.

To learn more, please see [react-hooks-testing-library-documentation](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/usage/basic-hooks)

> PS: Maybe you might wait for `@testing-library/react-hooks` to update
> their peer dependency requirement to support React 18.

To install this module:

```
npm install react-test-renderer@18 --save-dev
npm i @testing-library/react-hooks -D --legacy-peer-deps
```